# Who first described a statistical estimate as an approximation of a population parameter?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, frequentist, games, history

At some point in the history of statistics, there surely was a transition from thinking of statistical measures strictly as imperfect approximations of real quantities, to thinking of them as estimates of unobservable parameters of abstract population distributions. Similar transitions, from the material to the abstract, have occurred in other fields: the shift in mathematics credited to Pythagoras, say, or the shift in philosophy attributed to Plato. To whom can we attribute the paradigm shift in inferential statistics?

I don't think Bayes would qualify, given his view of probability as a belief. Graunt seems slightly early, Fisher and Pearson far too late. My inclination is toward more pure mathematicians, like Pascal, Montmort, and the Bernoullis.

Comment: Pascal (1650's) is too early: he was struggling with more basic material about probability, rather than statistics.  Graunt (a demographer) did nothing theoretical afaik.  The flavor of Jacob Bernoulli's *Ars Conjectandi,* with its law of large numbers, already suggests the conceptual move you describe.  That work is derived from diaries written in the 1680's and appeared posthumously in 1713.  BTW, what "shift in philosophy" are you referring to?  Many of the pre-Socratics, from Thales onward (200 years before Plato) were plenty abstract.

Comment: I'm referring to Plato's partitioning of reality into the ideal forms and their physical realities. Granted, Plato's theory of forms is necessarily derivative, as are all ideas--Homer didn't write the Iliad, Pythagoras wasn't the first guy to think of numbers abstractly, Euclid cribbed from others, etc. But we tend to associate these ideas with a certain guy, right or wrong. My point is, the origins of those ancient transitions are somewhat lost in the mists of the past, whereas we ought to be able to identify a first paper or book that expresses this idea, or at least the first extant mention

Comment: Put another way, who's the first person to write about this idea and either cite someone else or take for granted that people would know what he was talking about? The person before that is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Certainly by Gauss and Laplace you're getting a sense of estimation in the presence of noise, so presumably it comes well before that -- but you may not  necessarily discover a single momentous shift of viewpoint (a paradigm shift); often change like what you're looking for tends to come with clear precursors and its often something nearer to "lets clear up this concept that's already been around for decades by being clearer about our definitions and notation".